# Pretty Print Haxe JS Output

Tags: javascript, haxe

The Haxe JS output converts `if` statements into one-liners, making it difficult to do step-through debugging using a map.  Can I disable this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Not at the moment](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4542), but you could run everything through a processing script that accepts a source map.

Answer (score 1):

meanwhile I just put the `untyped __js__("debugger;");` keyword

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DebuggerUtil and import a static function or property. If a function is marked as inline, the function body content is put at the position from where you call it.

With that knowledge you can create something that looks similar to the debugger-keyword.

**Try it yourself: http://try.haxe.org/#D7058**

```
import DebugUtils.debugger;

class Test {
    static function main() {
        trace("Haxe is great!");
        debugger;
        trace("Debugging is great!");
    }

}

class DebugUtils {
    public static var debugger(get,null):Void;
    private static inline function get_debugger() {
        return untyped __js__("debugger");
    }
}
```